# How to load data to remote server using sstableloder?

Tags: cassandra

I am newbie to the cassandra, the situation is:

[1] I want to bulkload(bulk-upload) my cassandra data from my client PC into the "remote server A"

[2] the IPAddress of the remote server A is 192.168.**.**

[3] so I typed as follows from my client PC:

```
$ sstableloader -d 192.168.**.** [path/to/my/clientPC's/cassandra/columnFamily/Directory]
```

[4] the cassandra is running on both of clientPC and remote server A

then, I get the message like this...

```
Could not retrieve endpoint ranges:
```

I cant get what on earth is going on here... please somebody help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you are running the command from your C* data directory root, and then pass the relative path for the keyspace and columnFamily.  The target database must also have the same keyspace name and column family name.

So if your C* data dir in cassandra.yaml is defined as `/cassandra/data` and your keyspace is `ks1` and column family is `my_cf`, then cd to `/cassandra/data`, the run `sstableloader -d <ip> ks1/mv_cf`.

From http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/references/bulkloader

> Using sstableloader
>
> In binary installations, sstableloader is located in the
>   /bin directory.
>
> The sstableloader bulk loads the SSTables found in the directory
>    to the configured cluster. The parent directory of
>    is used as the keyspace name. For example to load an
>   SSTable named Standard1-he-1-Data.db into keyspace Keyspace1, the
>   files Keyspace1-Standard1-he-1-Data.db and
>   Keyspace1-Standard1-he-1-Index.db must be in a directory called
>   Keyspace1/Standard1/.
>
> bash sstableloader [options]
>
> Example:
>
> $ ls -1 Keyspace1/Standard1/ Keyspace1-Standard1-he-1-Data.db
>   Keyspace1-Standard1-he-1-Index $ /bin/sstableloader
>   -d localhost //

Also, make sure any sstableloader defaults (such as port) match your target C* cluster.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! It worked! Exactly because the cause of my failure is due to lack of the KeySpace and Column Family on the remote server! God bless you!